# codeigniter url with current page number

Tags: codeigniter

i need a help,
how to change the url style in codeigniter when using pagination,
i want something like this,
http://localhost/CI_doctrine/blog/filmnews/1 showing the current pagenumber instead of 
offset.
any help appreciated.
thank you 
from your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout identical post on codeigniter official forum. Might be helpful to you.

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/86437/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

please try this

```
         $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
```

By default, the URI segment will use the starting index for the items you are paginating. If you prefer to show the the actual page number, set this to TRUE.

or refer this link

```
    https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html
```